# misuse of aggregate function MAX() in ContentResolver

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying use the MAX() function of SQLite to get the Max value of column throught a custom ContentProvider's query method, but when I run the app it crashes, giving me the current error:

> 06-20 17:30:33.868 30109-30109/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.bpl.spart.bloodpressurelogbook, PID: 30109
>                                                      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: misuse of aggregate function MAX() (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, sistolica, diastolica, pulso FROM TablaTomasDePresion WHERE MAX(sistolica)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
>                                                          at db.TomasProvider.query(TomasProvider.java:48)
>                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1017)
>                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:238)
>                                                          at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
>                                                          at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
>                                                          at com.bpl.spart.bloodpressurelogbook.pestanaGraficos$1.onItemSelected(pestanaGraficos.java:95)
>                                                          at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:931)
>                                                          at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:920)
>                                                          at android.widget.AdapterView.-wrap1(AdapterView.java)
>                                                          at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:890)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

This is the code where I'm calling the method:

```
                   final String[] projection = {Contrato.Columnas._ID,Contrato.Columnas.SISTOLICA,Contrato.Columnas.DIASTOLICA,Contrato.Columnas.PULSO};
                    final String select  = "MAX(" + Contrato.Columnas.SISTOLICA + ")";

                    Cursor c = resolver.query(Contrato.URI_CONTENIDO_BASE,projection,select,null,null);

                    if(c.moveToNext()){
                        String sisq = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Contrato.Columnas.SISTOLICA));
                        sistolicaMAQ.setText(sisq);

                        String diaq = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Contrato.Columnas.DIASTOLICA));
                        diastolicaMAQ.setText(diaq);

                        String pulq = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Contrato.Columnas.PULSO));
                        pulsoMAQ.setText(pulq);
                    }
```

So, the Question is How can I correct this erros?

Comment: EITHER use `>= ALL` and a subselect to restrict the results, OR use `ORDER BY` to sort the rows by `sistolica` and fetch only the first row.

Comment: In terms of performance, Wich query will require less time MAX() or ORDER BY sistolica ASC in a DB with a large number of registers?

Comment: I don't know.  You could try both.